# What should be configured when placing a load balancer in front of k8s master(s)

Tags: kubernetes

I have a running cluster with single master. A load balancer(kube.company.com) is configured to accept traffic at 443 and forwards it to the k8s master 6443.

I tried to change my ~/.kube/config `server` field definition from $masterIP:6443 to kube.company.com:443.

It throws the error x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.

I guess there should be some configuration that should be done to make this work, I just can't find it in the official docs

This is a bare metal setup using k8s version 1.21.2, containerd in RHEL env. The load balancer is nginx. Cluster is installed via kubeadm

Comment: How did you deploy kubernetes? `kubeadm`?

Comment: yes kubeadm following standard installation in docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `kubeadm` to deploy a cluster, if you want to use a custom name to access the `Kubernetes API Server`, you need to specify the `--apiserver-cert-extra-sans` flag of `kubeadm init`.

> Optional extra Subject Alternative Names (SANs) to use for the API Server serving certificate. Can be both IP addresses and DNS names.

This is untested, but theoretically if you want to do this on an existing cluster, you should be able to log in `in every master node` and run this:

```
# remove current apiserver certificates
sudo rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*

# generate new certificates
sudo kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=<your custom dns name here>
```

Comment: actually since the one i posted is not working, i went straight to kubeadm reset the current single master and include that flag in my kubeadm init https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/103680, i'll look for other errors again..

Comment: follow up question, what's the sense behind the need to specify this when using custom domain vs when accessing it from my local machine?

Comment: Sorry I don't get the question

Comment: In the working setup, I'm accessing kube-apiserver from my local machine. With load balancer, why do I need to specify a cert sans specifying my custom domain. What's the logic behind it is asking for cert now, where in it doesn't require that when accessing kube server from my local

Comment: In the local machine do you use the kubeconfig file generated by kubeadm? The whole point is the hostname used to connect to the cluster, and that's written in the kubeconfig

Comment: saw the issue, it's just my load balancer. this is happening when my front end port is at 443. When I change this to 6443, it works just fine.